# Difference between "Elect as" and "Elect to"

Tags: prepositions, differences

What is the difference betweeen  "Elect as" and "Elect to"?

Can't find the difference in dictionaries.

Sources:

- Elect to
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-elect
- The sentence I read which caused me confused.

"Two years later, he was elected to the House of Representatives."
https://englishteststore.net/voa/makingnation/lesson1.html

- Elect as
  [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/詞典/英語/elect](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/elect)

Comment: Sources have beed added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the preposition.

When you elect someone **as** President (say), they **become** President.

However, if you want to use **to** then you can only elect someone to the *office* of President — that is, the status, the position of *being President.* They are elected and moved into that position.

> The people elected Peter Bloggs as President.
> The people elected Peter Bloggs to the office/position of President.

In practice, these statements mean the same thing, and are simply different ways of expressing the result of the election. However each preposition is used in its own way.
You can't elect Peter Bloggs *to President; nor can you elect him *as the office of President.

You can elect someone **to** a particular place, like *"to* the House of Representatives". This is the same use of *to* — they are elected and moved into the House to do that particular job.

Note that the adjectival suffix *-elect* is different. That simply indicates that although someone has been successful in an election, they haven't yet taken up the position. Thus a President-elect has been successful in the election but has not yet been sworn in; a bishop-elect has been chosen but not yet enthroned.

[Office: see [office²](https://www.lexico.com/definition/office) in Lexico]